# Portable output from `script`

Tags: terminal, typescript

I have recorded my session which looks good on my terminal (when doing `cat typescript`), but shows gibberish everywhere else.

Is it possibile to use knowledge of my terminal to produce a portable output using command line?

At "small scale" I can workaround this by copying scrollback buffer and pasting into a new file. This proves my terminal knows how to do this!

EDIT: Just realized that this may be very specific, so I'll share that I used tmux but hopefully there exists a general solution using terminal capabilies etc.